# Processing a file by two template handlers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, sass

I'm using Rails 3.1 and I'm trying to process a file with two template handlers.

Well, I have registered a new template handler for .scss files. Now  want to process files like this one:

app/views/custom_css/stylesheet.css.scss.erb

Through 2 template handlers. First ERB and after that SCSS. This way we can have dynamic scss files.

I tried this template handler:

```
class ActionView::Template::Handlers::Sass

  def initialize options = {}
    @options = options
  end

  def erb_handler
    @erb_handler ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
  end

  def call template
    source = erb_handler.call(template)

    <<CODE
compiler = Compass::Compiler.new *Compass.configuration.to_compiler_arguments
options  = compiler.options.merge(#{@options.inspect})
Sass::Engine.new(source, options).render
CODE
  end
end
```

However, in that case **source** equals to this:

```
"@output_buffer = output_buffer || ActionView::OutputBuffer.new;@output_buffer.safe_concat('$background_color: \"#ff0000\";\n\n$test: ');@output_buffer.append= ( 'test' );@output_buffer.safe_concat(';\n\n.container {\n  background-color: $background_color;\n}\n');@output_buffer.to_s"
```

and I can't easily extract only "the real source".

Any ideas how this could be done?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution? Because I'm trying to do something like that, but I can't get the "real" source.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline already support stacking pre-processors?

http://asciicasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

Comment: Sure, however in the assets pipeline you don't have access to the application environment. The assets are served as separate and independent requests.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to return a string just like ERB does.

Here is my handler which inline CSS code :

```
module EmvHandler
    def self.erb_handler
        @@erb_handler ||= ActionView::Template.registered_template_handler(:erb)
    end

    def self.call(template)
        compiled_source = erb_handler.call(template)
        options = {
           :warn_level => Premailer::Warnings::SAFE,
           :with_html_string => true
        }
        "Premailer.new((begin;#{compiled_source};end), #{options}).to_inline_css"
    end
end
```

**compiler_source** must be wrapped by a begin-end statement. Otherwise it will raise a syntax error.